# Does the machine configuration affect the accessibility of serialized output created using protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am using protobuf-net to encrypt, serialize and store the contents of an object into a file and am using contents of the file after decrypting and desiralizing into the original object.

The object can be decrypted, and deserialized perfectly through my application on the machine on which it was created but when the exact same application reads the exact same file when executed on another machine, it throws an exception asking me to refer to one of the existing questions on stackoverflow. I am unable to post the exact stacktrace right now but will be doing so shortly.

My question is - does the physical configuration of the machine on which the serialization and storage of an object into a file takes place have any bearing on its availability elsewhere?

I think this should not be the case as it would defeat the purpose of serialization and that there is a gap in my understanding.

All help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Thanks Marc! - for both the reply and the awesome library itself. I'll post back more details regarding the stack trace, the encryption technique used, and the length and bytes of the contents. Though I doubt that there is a problem in the encryption/decryption code logic since the same code creates and uses the file successfully on one machine. Overwriting an existing file can also be ruled out as the created files are named using a guid so the name  getting repeated is improbable. Could you please clarify on what exactly you mean by "by treating the file as text at some point"?

Comment: By text, I mean: have you at any point used something like Encoding, UTF8, StreamReader, StreamWriter, GetString, or anything like that? If you did: you've probably trashed the data. Protobuf data is not text.

Comment: @MarcGravell I will check the text usage like you mentioned above and reply...but would this make the application behave as described - ie if the the data is trashed due to the reasons mentioned, would it throw an exception on one machine but function properly on another? The same problem would be displayed in both cases irrespective of the machine right?

Comment: @user156858 without a repro I can only speculate; I was guessing it was the "transfer" step that was broken, hence it works ok on the machine that created the file but didn't yet transfer it.

Comment: @MarcGravell true - ill get back with more details - till then it is pointless - it will only result in speculation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there shouldn't be any dependency on machine configuration. As examples, it is perfectly reasonable to serialize data on regular .net and then deserialize it on windows phone, or on unity in a browser, on in iOS via MonoTouch.

My first concern, then, is whether it truly is the "exact same file". In particular, **after** decryption (since some encryption techniques *do* use machine configuration, but that is nothing to do with protobuf-net)

I strongly advise checking the length and the bytes after decryption (or using a hashing function if it is large). Common errors:

- an error in your encrypt/decrypt code
- overwriting a pre-existing file with less data, leaving old garbage at the end (in which case: be sure to truncate the file)
- corruption when transferring the file between machines, for example by treating the file as text at some point

If you have a reproducible example (either here, or via email if you can't make it available out here in public), it may be possible to say more.

Comment: Thanks Marc! - for both the reply and the awesome library itself.

Comment: @user1526858 let me know if you can't figure it out. If you are able to share a reproducible example project (I.e. where I can press f5 and see it not work), I might be able to find the problem pretty quickly. Entirely up to you.